# SQL ignoring a column while pivoting but need that column in the selected output

Tags: sql, pivot

I am using the below sql query to pivot on 'Month' column and it works fine.

```
select  col1,col2
,[1] as 'Jan'
,[2] as 'Feb'
,[3] as 'Mar'
,[4] as 'Apr'
,[5] as 'May'
,[6] as 'Jun'
,[7] as 'Jul'
,[8] as 'Aug'
,[9] as 'Sep'
,[10] as 'Oct'
,[11] as 'Nov'
,[12] as 'Dec'
from
(
    select col1,col2,Month 
    from @TempTable
) d
pivot
(
     max(col2)
     for Month in ([1], [2], [3],[4],
                   [5], [6],[7], [8], 
                   [9],[10], [11], [12])
) piv
```

this table @TempTable has another column 'CreatedDate'.
I dont want to use CreatedDate column in pivot but need this column in select query.....
How can I achieve this...the below query doesn't work, since the subquery doesn't select this column.

Adding CreatedDate(the records having different timestamp) in subquery returns each month in separate rows....so for the pivot to work as expected, I shld ignore CreatedDate in subquery....

the current output of pivot......
[image]

if CreatedDAte is included in the subquery, the output is
[image]

```
select  col1,col2,CreatedDate
,[1] as 'Jan'
,[2] as 'Feb'
,[3] as 'Mar'
,[4] as 'Apr'
,[5] as 'May'
,[6] as 'Jun'
,[7] as 'Jul'
,[8] as 'Aug'
,[9] as 'Sep'
,[10] as 'Oct'
,[11] as 'Nov'
,[12] as 'Dec'
from
(                               
     select col1,col2,Month 
     from @TempTable
) d
pivot
(                                
    max(col2)
    for Month in ([1], [2], [3],[4], 
                  [5], [6],[7], [8], 
                  [9],[10], [11], [12])
) piv
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below include the `'CreatedDate'` column in your select `query` while using the `pivot` operation,

```
SELECT col1, col2, CreatedDate,
       [1] as 'Jan',
       [2] as 'Feb',
       [3] as 'Mar',
       [4] as 'Apr',
       [5] as 'May',
       [6] as 'Jun',
       [7] as 'Jul',
       [8] as 'Aug',
       [9] as 'Sep',
       [10] as 'Oct',
       [11] as 'Nov',
       [12] as 'Dec'
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, Month, CreatedDate
    FROM @TempTable
) d
PIVOT (
    MAX(col2)
    FOR Month IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
) piv;
```

In the `subquery` d, include the '`CreatedDate`' column along with 'col1', 'col2', and 'Month' from @TempTable. Then, in the outer query, you can select 'col1', 'col2', 'CreatedDate', and the pivoted columns 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', and so on.
Now, you will have the 'CreatedDate' column available in the select query while performing the `pivot` operation.

Comment: yes...i understand that will ...but including the createdDate column (with different timestamp) actually pivoting multiple rows.....each month in separate row....
So for the pivot to work as expected, i shld ignore 'CreatedDate' in the subquery.....

Comment: please refer the image attached in the question

Comment: CreatedDate had same date and different timestamp.So including createdDate in subquery returned multiple records. Now made sure the CreatedDate column had same date and timestamp and also included CreatedDAte in the subquery and it worked.

Comment: well glad it worked anything that you would want changed from whatever is right now ?

Comment: i didnt get your question...

Comment: R u happy with what you have working or you  are looking for improvisations to that